# @media Cannot get the sections to stack

Tags: html, css, media

I am trying to have my section's stack on vertically when the window gets smaller or on mobile. I am using the @media only screen and (max-width: 1024px) command. It most likely is something simple but I am NOT able to see where is my error. Any help would be more than welcome. Thank you...    HTML and CSS is as follows:

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 1024px) 

{
 #main
 {
  width: auto;
 }
    
    #brass img
    {
        display: none; 
    }

    #Experience, #Education
 {
        width: 100%; 
  text-align: left;
        float: none;
        height: auto; 
    }
    
    #About
    {
        width: 100%;
 
    }
    
}

#main
{
 width: 900px;
 margin: auto;
}

#logo, header h1
{
 display: inline-block;
 margin-bottom: 0px;
}

#Experience
{
 position: fixed;
 right: 45%;
 top: 20%;
 word-wrap: break-word;
 width: 25%;
 text-align: justify; 
}

#Education
{
 word-wrap: break-word;
 width: 25%;
 position: fixed;
 right: 15%; 
 top: 20%;
```

```html
<div id="brass">
  <section id="left side"> <img src="pic/brass.png" alt="brass" id="brass" /> </section>
</div>
<div id="Experience">
  <section>
    <h2>Experience</h2>
    <ul>
      <li></li>
    </ul>
  </section>
</div>
<div id="Education">
  <section>
    <h2>Education</h2>
    <ul>
      <li></li>
    </ul>
  </section>
</div>
<div id="About">
  <section>
    <h2>About Me</h2>
    <ul>
      <li></li>
    </ul>
  </section>
</div>
<footer></footer>
```

Comment: ...and that doesn't look as clear as I hoped....  Basically its just 3 <section>'s that I put with their own <div>'s.  I am not able to get them to stack, I "thought" I have tried every possible combination but I am clearly missing something.  Thank you for whoever takes a look at this

Comment: please post a picture to show difference between pc and mobile view

Comment: @Mholmes85 Can you add the code where you try to use the media query?

Comment: @Mholmes85, put the screenshots on [imgur](https://imgur.com/) and link to them.

Comment: @media (min-width:1400px) and (max-width:3600px) { } try this one

Comment: I posted the screen shots here.  https://imgur.com/a/ye1Zh

Comment: So far I have cleaned up the html/css files.  Absolutely cannot get it to work for the life of me.

Comment: Thank you for the comments/help.  Turns out I was over complicating what I had learned so far... I had a few default properties working against each other and I was stuck.  I removed all the access css that I didn't (really) understand. GOt it to work smoothly without a problem and moved on.  I also am learning the Bootstrap grid now and that is amazing. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do you want this? click `Run code snippet` then click `full page` then resize your browser window

```css
section {
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
  section {
    float: none;
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div>
  <section id="leftside">
    <div id="brass">
      <img src="pic/brass.png" alt="brass" id="brass" />
    </div>
  </section>
  <section>
    <div id="Experience">
      <h2>Experience</h2>
      <ul>
        <li></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section>
    <div id="Education">
      <h2>Education</h2>
      <ul>
        <li></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section>
    <div id="About">
      <h2>About Me</h2>
      <ul>
        <li></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </section>
  <div>
    <footer></footer>
```